# Executing date field with null in plsql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, rdbms

Hello I have a procedure and questions about it. This procedure is used for extracting data then inserting them into one table. What I want to do is that when executing the procedure if pid_billdate is null, it should use previous months' last dasy as a parameter. I have already tried out in procedure definition line but didn't worked out properly. So how can I make this change? I need to add this control into procedure.

My second question is how can I test it(I mean how to enter null value?)

```
BEGIN
   GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(); -- or is it should be GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(null) ?
END;
```

I am open to any advices.
Note: I have only records about 8/31/2021 so I have already tried to change value -1 to -2 in first line for testing but didn't insert to GPU_INV_TEST table.
My script of procedure is below, thank you from now.

```
    create or replace procedure GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(pid_billdate DATE DEFAULT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1))) is
c_limit   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10000;

CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate;

TYPE prod_ids_t IS TABLE OF apld_bill_rt.intl_prod_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_prod_ids   prod_ids_t;
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table GPU_INV_TEST';

  OPEN c1;

  LOOP
     FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_prod_ids LIMIT c_limit;
     
     EXIT WHEN l_prod_ids.COUNT = 0;

    FORALL indx IN 1 .. l_prod_ids.COUNT
    
      INSERT INTO GPU_INV_TEST
         SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                bill_acct ba2,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx)
UNION
    SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba1.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                --AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx);

      
    COMMIT;  
    
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value is correctly calculated:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -1)) result FROM DUAL;

RESULT
----------
30.09.2021

SQL>
```

The only place where `pid_billdate` is used is in cursor's `select` statement:

```
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
        FROM apld_bill_rt abr, acct_bill ab
       WHERE     abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
             AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
             AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
             AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate;          --> here
```

As you said that it

> didn't worked out properly

I presume that no rows were inserted into `gpu_inv_test` table.  There are two possibilities:

- either cursor's `select` didn't return anything (so loop didn't execute at all)
- `select`s in `forall` didn't return anything (so, although there are some rows fetched by the cursor, `select`s didn't return any rows to be inserted into the table.

We can't really test it as we don't have your tables (and you used bunch of them in `FROM` clauses), so it is you who should test it.

---

As of your second question: both options are OK.

Comment: Hello, this procedure is working if I test it with-- begin
    GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(to_date('31/08/2021','DD/MM/YYYY'));
end;-- script. So it doesnt work only for this null option case.

Comment: Can we add an IF control? I tried but couldn't successfull because of syntax. I am newbie. ---IF pid_billdate IS NULL THEN USE
    LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)) = pid_billdate;

  END IF;  ---

Comment: As I said: did you check whether cursor's SELECT returns any rows for 30.09.2021? As of IF: you don't really need it. NVL would do, e.g. `where ab.bill_date = nvl(pid_billdate, last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1)))`. If you really, really want to use IF, then `if pid_billdate is null then l_billdate := last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1)); end if;` but it means that you'll have to have a local variable which will be used instead of pid_billdate (I named it L_BILLDATE).

Comment: nvl solution is worked, thank you.